# Permission denied while creating a database in HIVE

Tags: hadoop

In hive i am trying to create database for practice purpose but i face issue from hdfs stating
FAILED : execution error .return code 1from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apahe.hadoop.security.AccessControlExeption Permission denied : user=root,access= Write,inode= "/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x

Answer (score 0):

You are running as root user, and the root user doesn't have access to the directory. For create database it is trying to create a directory for the database, which lies under the /user directory.

Either run hive from some other user, which has permissions, else provide adequate permissions to root user.

Or if you are doing this for testing purpose can set `dfs.permissions.enabled` configuration as false in the hdfs-site.xml and restart the namenode. This will disable the permission checks itself.

Comment: Thanks for your input tried with the permission enable config but again facing same issue . Is there any way to change the owner from /user to some other directory.

Comment: did you restart the namenode after setting dfs.permissions.enabled as false in hdfs-site.xml Post that it can not throw ACE. Another thing would be to do chmod -R 777 /user to give all permissions, or if you want to change the user chown -R user:group /user